# JSON4S + Jackson does not serialize properties of the superclass

Tags: java, scala, jackson, lombok, json4s

I'm using json4s with the jackson serializer in a scala project. My transfer objects are defined in a regular Java library. I'm also using Lombok to generate constructors/getter/setter/etc. They look as follows:

```
@Data
public abstract class Identified {
    private Long id;
}

@Data
public class Car extends Identified {
    private Integer maxSpeed;
}
```

The problem is that the json of a car lacks the id property of the superclass. It looks like this:

```
{
  "maxSpeed":null
}
```

In scala, I define this implicit

```
override implicit def json4sJacksonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats
```

I've often used Jackson in regular Java projects and have never come across this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't you forget `extends Identified`? I guess it's unrelated to Lombok as it only creates your getters and setters and Jackson probably works with fields directly.

Comment: That was a typo in this example. Fixed.

Comment: The type name in your abstract class is missing and the Car does not extend the abstract class.

Comment: Roel, sorry.. messed up the previous edit. Double checked it this time. That was not the issue (would not even compile in that case of course).